# Recess framework, relationship "in" does not exist

Tags: php, recess

I am using recess framework in php to write web services for my iPhone app. I am using codes like the following to get the records that country in the array I gave,

```
 $testtable = new testTable();
 $countryArray = $decoded_params["country"];
 $records = $testtable->in('country', $countryArray);
```

But an error occurred when I was using these codes saying that Relationship "in" does not exist. Anyone met this problem? And if what I have done is wrong, how can I do a "in" query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this was added at some point.

Your best bet is to clone the latest version from the github repo -
https://github.com/recess/recess

You might also try this:

```
$records = $testtable->in('country', implode(',',$countryArray));
```